# Can you export the results of a network analysis (eg: Service Area) to ArcGIS online?

Tags: networking, web, arcgis, analysis, esri

I am trying to export an analysis that I have undertaken in ArcGIS for Desktop to ArcGIS Online. I have attempted to share it as a Map Service and I have encountered issues with caching (I restricted it to the area seen in the data frame but caching does not work, it pauses for hours). I have also tried to restrict the number of levels but no avail.

I should also add that I do not access to ArcGIS for Server, and am solely exporting this through ArcGIS  for Desktop.

My question is simply, is there a way to exporting this data so that I display it in a ArcGIS Online Web Application? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You post it as a Map Service, restrict the map to map extent only and then make sure to add the service to existing data. The dataset will then project properly alongside the other datasets.